# Using Multiple PayPal Email Addresses

Tags: magento, paypal

I have two email addresses set up on PayPal. Both are confirmed, one is set to primary.
And these two email address are used for two different website for accepting money. My websites are based on Magento. Both websites use Standard PayPal and Express Checkout.

But the problems is that transactions from both websites state that payment is sent to primary email.

Where can I set up to sort payments received by which email address was paid, track transactions based on source (different websites).

Answer (score 0):

The [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/) for the transactions would allow you to distinguish between the two using the receiver_id parameter, which is the unique ID of the account as opposed to an email address.